# Create zkProof onchain

Tags: solidity, verify, zksnark, zero-knowledge

Is it possible to create ZK-SNARKS proofs and verify them, all onchain, with solidity, without reveling the witness?

The proving and verifying keys could be created offchain, but these two would have to be onchain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely do the prover, here's a library that creates the Verifier.sol used in tornado cash and other zk contracts:  https://github.com/iden3/snarkjs.

The big issue with doing everything on-chain and keeping it secret is that everything on-chain is public.  Compilation issues aside, if you wanted both sides on-chain (and to keep it anonymous), you'd basically need to have another off-chain zk-proof to prove you know witness...which basically negates the point of putting the one-side onchain.  the problem is where's the secret you're trying to keep and when do you reveal it.  You want to keep the secret off-chain and it's necessary for the proof.

Comment: I can keep the secret and generate the proof offchain, or keep the secret offchain and generate the proof onchain (if that's even possible), but once the proof is onchain, what stops someone from just pulling it from the contract and use it? I'd have to be generating proof after proof, which I can't do since my system doesn't involve offchain servers. It's all onchain.

Comment: have a link?  curious to see what it looks like

Comment: No no. That's my question haha that's the main problem I'm facing. Either how to keep the witness a secret -without doing it offchain- or how to stop someone from grabbing the proof from the contract if I only use one